# How to pull private docker image from GitLab container registry using DockerOperator in Airflow 2.0?

Tags: python, docker, gitlab, airflow, container-registry

I have installed Airflow 2.0 using Docker on AWS and trying to pull my own private docker image GitLab container registry using DockerOperator but getting permission denied.

How I can pull my docker image from GitLab and How I can create a connection for the Docker image GitLab registry?

Dag file [link](https://github.com/mobinalhassan/StackoverflowQuestions/blob/main/java_test_dag.py)
Docker yml file [link](https://github.com/mobinalhassan/StackoverflowQuestions/blob/main/docker-compose.yaml)

My dag Code:

```
java_test_scheduler = DockerOperator(
    task_id='Java-hello-world-test-scheduler',
    image='registry.gitlab.com/mobinalhassan/jamay_aeronova:latest',
    auto_remove=True,
    force_pull=True,
    dag=dag
)
```

I also tried by adding docker volums:

```
- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
- $HOME/.ssh:/root/.ssh:ro
- $HOME/.docker:/root/.docker
```

Error:

```
sock.connect(self.unix_socket) PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dag is missing dag_conn_id definition when pulling from private docker registry:

`If a login to a private registry is required prior to pulling the image, a Docker connection needs to be configured in Airflow and the connection ID be provided with the parameter docker_conn_id.`

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_api/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker/index.html

Comment: I have tried this but failed, There is no documentation on how to create a connection link...

Comment: This is the link I have created...docker://gitlab+68hzvkEtonsazVoxNHsy:mobin@registry.gitlab.com
but not working, Can you explain that..

Comment: Are you using airflow connections? https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html 
then use your conn id (for example 'gitlab_conn_id') in dockeroperator initialization code as parameter `docker_conn_id='gitlab_conn_id' `

Comment: Yes! actually, I did the whole thing, setting up the connection and giving Id in DockerOperator as you have mentioned...

Answer (score 0):

1. I have tried without docker you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67372027/3152654) for details on that
2. I wanted to keep least dependency on airflow and hence didn't create the connection from airflow whose details are mentioned in the above referenced answer link
3. As far as your [dag link](https://github.com/mobinalhassan/StackoverflowQuestions/blob/main/java_test_dag.py) is concerned, I had tried similar approach but could not make it work with `image='registry.gitlab.com/mobinalhassan/jamay_aeronova:latest'`, however it did work out when I removed the `:latest` and use it like `image='registry.gitlab.com/mobinalhassan/jamay_aeronova',`, try this out and let me know if it works
4. For full details on pulling private docker image, I have jotted down a step by step tutorial which you can refer at - [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67372027/3152654)

Comment: Okay, let me try

Comment: @MobinAlHassan edited and added the link to the step by step tutorial